# How to make a British-citizen father take responsibility for child in Africa

Tags: uk-citizens, legal, children

I am 28 years old, and gave birth to a beautiful girl named Angel. The father is a British citizen. He has recently abandoned me and our little baby here in Cameroon. I wish to know what measures I can take to make him provide for his daughter.

Comment: Were you married to him? Is he listed on her birth certificate. Are you in communication with him at all?

Comment: yes he is listed in her birth certificate and was taking full responsibility, but stop months ago. Am not married to him yet...i just want him to take responsibilities since i lost my job and things are harder.

Answer (score 5):

In the absence of expanded details asked by @ouflak whether you were married to this individual and whether his name is on the child's birth certificate, you may have the option of requesting a child support order in Cameroon.

Understand that the [UK courts may not be able to enforce such an order](https://www.gov.uk/child-maintenance-if-one-parent-lives-abroad/paying-parent-lives-in-the-uk) since Cameroon does not participate in what are known as Reciprocal Enforcement of Maintenance Orders (REMO). Should you get a child maintenance order in Cameroon, your ex-partner could go through the UK courts to challenge the decision.  However you decide to proceed, you may want [guidance of a solicitor in the UK](https://www.gov.uk/find-a-legal-adviser).

Answer (score 4):

If you and the child's other parent cannot agree on maintenance, or if the other parent is recalcitrant, you can submit an application to the [UK Child Maintenance Service](https://childmaintenanceservice.direct.gov.uk/public/). This is a publicly funded service available to UK residents.  There is also the [Child Support Agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_Support_Agency) which is available for especially difficult cases.  They have a cadre of enforcers with foreign contacts who can be ruthless.

The 'best practices' advice is to examine the rules and see if you qualify to submit an application. The starting page for you is [Use the Child Maintenance Service or Child Support Agency (CSA)](https://www.gov.uk/child-maintenance/overview).

Take note that these agencies have been hit hard by budget cuts and most of their services will be ended in 2017, so you need to hurry.  The [answer provided by Dorothy](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9756/how-to-make-a-british-citizen-father-take-responsibility-for-child-in-africa/9758#9758) (to whom a tip of the hat), explains that a solicitor can be helpful. This is great advice and should be heeded with alacrity.

Comment: Could OP still do this if she's in Cameroon with the baby and only the father is in the UK?

Comment: Absolutely yes!  If the Cameroon government issued child maintenance, the UK will enforce it within the UK.

Comment: he says he wants a DNA test to make sure its his after 7 yrs and birth certificate bearing his name..i told him its ok he is free to do it ..after the uk consulate provided me wit a list of legal law firms for me to get in touch with so that they can follow up with the case..they send him a mail and he said he wants the cameroon embassy to organise with the uk embassy because he does not want to deal with crocks..so please advice me on what to do next because i have tried all i can on this and she is not doing well health wise and she stop school ..